# How to preserve formatting and remove hidden data while converting from PDF to text using Poppler-utils

Tags: python, python-3.x, poppler

I am having a PDF in the format below

```
**Cutomer PO number Invoice  Date1  Date2     Currency**

11235 po-689573/gqmIN 30/12/2018 11/01/2019 200,234.00
```

so I convert the pdf to text using.

```
pdftotext -layout -f sample.pdf sample.txt
```

Here is the problem, the line is overflowing to the next line,as given below.

```
11235 po-689573/gqmr312
                       IN-345 30/12/2018 11/01/2019 200,234.00
```

I want poppler not to take all the hidden texts `gqmr312` and `IN-345`.

And return everything in a single line.

Like the pdf format,as given below.

```
11235 po-689573/gqmIN 30/12/2018 11/01/2019 200,234.00
```

Is there a way to acheive this in python.